# SIM7000 ATD command returns ERROR, how to fix?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm currently working on a project that is required to dial a number in the event of a trigger, I have the dfrobot shield currently set up.

I have managed to get it to be connected to the network using 4g LTE and send an SMS. But when I send:

`ATD+44XXXXXXXXX`

It returns

`ERROR`

Is there any specific AT commands that need to be sent to enable dialling of phone numbers?

Current set up:

- Arduino Uno
- DFRobot SIM7000E
- 12v external input